# Unit testing flow API Calls from viewModel and varifying StateFlow data

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to test the API response flow using mockk where my data flow is as following

`ProductViewModel.kt`

```
@HiltViewModel
class ProductViewModel @Inject constructor(
   val repository: ProductRepository
) : BaseViewModel() {

    private val _productsResponseState: MutableStateFlow<ResponseState<List<Product>>> =
        MutableStateFlow(ResponseState.LoadingWithData(listOf()))
    val productsResponseState: StateFlow<ResponseState<List<Product>>> =
        this._productsResponseState.asStateFlow()

    fun getProducts(search: String? = null) = viewModelScope.launch {
        _productsResponseState.value = ResponseState.Loading()
        repository.remote.getProducts(search)
            .catch { error ->
                _productsResponseState.value = ResponseState.Failure(error)
                Log.e("#product - error", error.message.toString())
                println("#product - error: ${error.message.toString()}")
            }.stateIn(
                viewModelScope,
                SharingStarted.Eagerly,
                _productsResponseState.value.data?.let {
                    ResponseModel(it, 0, 0, 0)
                }
            ).collectLatest {
                it?.let {
                    _productsResponseState.value = ResponseState.Success(it.products)
                    Log.d("#product - response", "Products - $it")
                    println("#product - response: Products - $it")
                }
            }
    }
}

data class ProductRepository @Inject constructor(
    val remote: ProductRemoteDataSource,
    val local: ProductLocalDataSource
) : BaseRepository()

class ProductRemoteDataSourceImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val productApi: ProductApi
) : ProductRemoteDataSource

class ProductLocalDataSourceImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val productDao: ProductDao
) : ProductLocalDataSource
```

Where `ProductRemoteDataSource, ProductLocalDataSource, ProductApi and ProductDao` are interfaces

Following is my test class where I'm trying to mock the dependencies and call the function which collects the api flow and verifying the data stored in `productsResponseState: StateFlow`

`ProductViewModelTest.kt`

```
@MockK
private lateinit var productApi: ProductApi
@MockK
private lateinit var productDao: ProductDao
@MockK
private lateinit var remoteDataSource: ProductRemoteDataSource
@MockK
private lateinit var localDataSource: ProductLocalDataSource

@InjectMockKs
private lateinit var repository: ProductRepository
@InjectMockKs
private lateinit var remoteDataSourceImpl: ProductLocalDataSourceImpl
@InjectMockKs
private lateinit var localDataSourceImpl: ProductLocalDataSourceImpl

private lateinit var viewModel: ProductViewModel

@Before
fun setup() {
    MockKAnnotations.init(this, relaxed = true)
    viewModel = spyk(ProductViewModel(repository))
}

@Test
fun testGetProducts() = runTest {
    val mockResponse = Product(
        0, "", "", 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0, "", "laptops", "", listOf()
    )
    coEvery {
        repository.remote.getProducts()
    } returns flowOf(ResponseModel(listOf(mockResponse), 0, 0, 0))

    viewModel.getProducts("lap")

    coVerify {
        repository.remote.getProducts("lap")
    }
    assertEquals(
        listOf(mockResponse)[0].category,
        viewModel.productsResponseState.value.data?.get(0)?.category
    )
}
```

I'm getting an error after running this test which says that the fuction `getProducts` needs another argument.

```
Verification failed: call 1 of 1: ProductRemoteDataSource(remoteDataSource#4).getProducts(eq(lap), any())). Only one matching call to ProductRemoteDataSource(remoteDataSource#4)/getProducts(String, Continuation) happened, but arguments are not matching:
[0]: argument: null, matcher: eq(lap), result: -
[1]: argument: continuation {}, matcher: any(), result: +`
```